# vbs error-trapping on folder-listing

Tags: vbscript

I'm making a script to list all files within a folder.
The intention is to list all files within a specific folder on every server we have.
So I have an excel file with as first line every servername.

Of course I don't have rights on every server or there is no scripts folder; so sometimes i get a "path not found" error.
Eventhough I used `On Error Resume Next` it still throws the error.

I would need something like try - catch, but that doens't exists in vbs.
How can I  try to connect to folders and ignore when there's an error?

The offending lines is the `Set folder = ...`

```
Do While objSheet.Cells(1, intCol).Value <> ""
  intRow = 2
  sFolder ="\\" & objSheet.Cells(1, intCol).Value & "\C$\Scripts"
  'msgbox sFolder

  Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
  Set files = folder.Files
...
```

The full code: https://gist.github.com/076501c940e8388b5b39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a folder exists with fso.FolderExists(sFolder):

```
If fso.FolderExists(sFolder) then
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder) 
    Set files = folder.Files    

    For each file In files  
        'msgbox file.name
        objSheet.Cells(intRow, intCol).Value = file.Name
        introw = introw + 1 
    Next    
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    intCol = intcol+1
End if
```

Comment: I could have imagined this myself. :) Thank you